# Rails/ActiveRecord .where method naming collision with Ruby Gem class method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am working on a Ruby gem that will be a REST API wrapper.

What I would like to do is have a class that can be instantiated from the gem with a method similar to Rails/ActiveRecord 'where' method such that I can pass a SQL-like syntax in the method and have some JSON returned. Something like:

```
include 'my-gem'

test = MyGem::ClassExample.where('name like %test%')

# returns JSON object from REST API
```

My concern is if I were to include this gem into a Ruby on Rails application, would this 'where' method have a naming collision with ActiveRecord's 'where' or would the 'where' method be the one that I had defined in my class?

Basically, I *think* it should be okay, but I am scared of having to refactor a bunch of tests and rename a bunch of methods because of Rails magic/my ignorance.

---

By the way, I am not worried about sanitizing input, the REST API does not provide direct SQL/database access and it is a closed-source product. There is some configuration that needs to be done upfront that I have not included in this example, I just wanted to know if I could use this method name or if there were best practices/potential issues that I may be in conflict with.

Comment: As long as `MyGem::ClassExample` is not an `ActiveRecord::Base` descendant, you should have nothing to worry about.

Comment: Thank you for the comment! I figured that as long as it didn't touch ActiveRecord that I would be okay, I was just worried about some Rails magic happening behind the scenes (which the selected answer pointed out in regards to some of the top level classes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classes are namespaces.

If you define `where` on your own class and Rails defines `where` on another class you will not have a conflict. This is the case for both instance methods and class methods, which after all are just instance methods on the singleton class of the class.

However, if you were to define `where` on Object or another top-level class then you'll run into plenty of conflict because all classes are subclassing these classes.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I knew that there can be some deep sub-classing going on behind on the scenes but wasn't too familiar with Rails internals.